# php output formatting

Tags: php, syntax

i have this:

```
<?php 
$values = $cfs->get('promoter'); 
if (!empty($values)) {
    echo $cfs->get_labels('promoter');  
    echo implode(', ', array_keys($values));
}
?>
<br />
```

which prints something like this:

```
PromoterPromoter1, Promoter2
```

when i'd like something like this:

```
Promoter: Promoter1, Promoter2
```

also, how could i include the `<br />`within the php, so if the field is blank, the line break is also excluded?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 
$values = $cfs->get('promoter'); 
if (!empty($values)) {
    echo $cfs->get_labels('promoter').": ";  
    echo implode(', ', array_keys($values))."<br />";
}
?>
```

Use PHP's concatenation operator - i.e. a period.

Comment: thanks. i had initially done similar with improper syntax: `echo $cfs->get_labels('promoter'.": ");`

Comment: Ah, yeah. All that is doing is passing "promotor:" to get_labels. You get used to it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append a string `": "` to the end

```
echo $cfs->get_labels('promoter').": ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$values = $cfs->get('promoter'); 
if (!empty($values)) {
    $word = "";
    $word .= $cfs->get_labels('promoter');
    $word .= ": ";
    $word .= implode(', ', array_keys($values));
    $word .= "<br />";
    echo $word;
}
?>
```